# rejson=py example not working on python 3.6

Tags: python, redis, redisjson

Trying to work through setting up ReJSON with Python3.  I am running on Ubuntu 16.04 in windows (WSL) and have Redis and ReJSON working.

Have simplified the python in the https://github.com/RedisLabs/rejson-py docs to isolate the problem:

```
from rejson import Client, Path

rj = Client(host='localhost', port=6379)

obj = {
    'answer': 42,
    'arr': [None, True, 3.14],
    'truth': {
        'coord': 'out there'
    }
}
rj.jsonset('obj', Path.rootPath(), obj)

temp = rj.jsonget('obj', Path('.truth.coord'))
```

The final line errors with:

```
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

I know the obj has been written as can be seen in the redis-cli:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.GET obj
"{\"answer\":42,\"arr\":[null,true,3.1400000000000001],\"truth\":{\"coord\":\"out there\"}}"
```

Any Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Solved.  Need to add decode_responses into the client setup:

```
rj = Client(host='localhost', port=6379, decode_responses=True)
```